# ANTLR 4 Parser match any token

Tags: antlr, antlr4

quick question (hopefully).

I want my parser to accept any token between two certain tokens.

So in my particular case it looks like this:

```
XPATH: 'xpath';

BRACKET_OPEN: '(';

BRACKET_CLOSED: ')';

xpathvar
:
    XPATH BRACKET_OPEN (any token or char between here) BRACKET_CLOSED
;
```

I already tried to make a `ANY: .;` token but that either never matched or matched always.

---

So i would want the rule `xpathvar` to match
`xpath( anything here, even special chars()!$[]!)`

Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: You can use `.` inside parser rules to match any token, but that doesn't help you completely because, if you want to allow parentheses inside, you'll need a way to count them. `.*` or `.*?` would stop at the last or first closing parentheses respectively, but you actually want to stop at the one that matches the opening parenthesis after the `XPATH`.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
xpathvar
 : XPATH parens
 ;

parens
 : BRACKET_OPEN ( ~( BRACKET_OPEN | BRACKET_CLOSED ) | parens )* BRACKET_CLOSED
 ;
```

where `~( BRACKET_OPEN | BRACKET_CLOSED )` matches any token (not any character!) except a `BRACKET_OPEN` and `BRACKET_CLOSED`.